# Restrict users from being added into multiple groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, sharepoint-permissions

I have created 2 SharePoint groups in the SharePoint Online. These groups are for 2 different projects with 2 different set of permission for a document library.

I want to check if it is possible to avoid member of 1 group being added to another group, when adding users in bulk accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge there is no way to avoid users been added to another group. You can always do permission check and remove permission when you find a users is granted permission accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to avoid adding one user to multiple groups.

But you can avoid this by changing group settings to **edit the membership of the group** to certain set of users only (maybe Site Owners).

This way only site owners will be able to add/remove the users from that particular group.

For Example, Set your group settings like this:

[image]